# JavaFX: How to find the x,y of a specific point along a Circle given only the radius and the center x,y position?

Tags: java, javafx, geometry

In JavaFX, there is the possibility to create a circle shape. This, however, only seems to offer the radius through `circle#getRadius()`.

Essentially, given a specific point (either in radians or degrees),  I want to find the x,y position that correlates with that spot along the circle's perimeter

How would I go about finding it?

Comment: How do you define the point you want to obtain? Radians I presume...? If so, a geometric solution in easy, or you can you a Point2D etc...

Comment: *"only seems to offer the radius through `circle#getRadius()`"* How else would you expect it to offer you it's radius, if not with a getter method? --- *"at a specified point"* Specified how? If all you have are center position and radius, that identifies *all* the points on the circle. --- Your question is not making much sense.

Comment: What I want to find is, given a specific point (either in radians or degrees), for it to find the x,y position that correlates with that spot along the circle's perimeter.

Comment: Please edit your question with what you just added in your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple geometric approach, using `awt`'s [Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html):

```
double radius = circle.getRadius();
double angleInRad = getInputAngle();
Point p = new (circleCenterX,circleCentery);
p.translate(Math.sin(angleInRad)*radius, Math.cos(angleInRad)*radius);
```

Now, you can just print the `x,y` contents of the `Point` object.